# Google Blogger API - Unauthorized User does not have permission to create new post

Tags: google-api, blogger, google-api-java-client

Getting the following error while using Google Blogger API to insert a New Post.

```
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Unauthorized
User does not have permission to create new post

at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:570)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
```

- Using Service Account , OAuth2 and GoogleCredential for generating
  accessToken.
- accessToekn gets created successfully.
- Somewhere I read that Google doesn't support service accounts for
  Blogger API.
- So tried using Client Id and Client Secret to get the code which can 
  again be used for getting access token using scope
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger".
- While doing that I got    the error saying "Not a valid scope".

What is the correct and working way to get the access token and then making a post call to insert new post ? If Blogger doesn't allow service accounts for blogger API and I need to authenticate the request before getting the access token, that will work for me too. I just need a mechanism to generate a valid access token for Blogger API that will later allow me to insert a post.

Currently My code looks like following. Appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

```
     String clientId = "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        String emailAddress = "xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
        HttpTransport httpTransport = null;
        try {
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        }

 catch (GeneralSecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

File file = new File("C://xxxx/IQ/PostBlogPost-d6158daa91a5.p12");

GoogleCredential credential = null;

try {
    credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
.setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger")).build();
        } catch(Exception ex){

        }

credential.refreshToken();

BloggerService myService = new BloggerService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
        myService.setAuthSubToken(credential.getAccessToken());
        myService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);


try {
 Entry myEntry = new Entry();
 myEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("test-title"));
 myEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("xxxxxxx"));

 // Ask the service to insert the new entry
 URL postUrl = new URL("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + "xxxx" + "/posts/default");
  myService.insert(postUrl, myEntry);
 } catch (ServiceException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Due to the fact that service accounts need to be preauthorized and there is no way to preauthorize someone for Blogger without them approving an email.The blogger API does not support service accounts you need to use OAuth2

Comment: Thanks @dalmto. Yeah I am now trying to use access token generated through Oauth 2 playground and making a Post request. That will work for me too.